# How do I efficiently query for records that share a year?

Tags: sqlite, date

I've got data that looks like

```
data
uid  id  date        value
1    a   1780-01-01  10
2    a   1780-01-02  11
3    a   1780-01-03  12
4    b   1780-01-01  10
...
999  a   1980-01-01  10
```

I'd like to know which `id`s have records between 1880 and 1900.  I currently
generate this big query (which I believe works):

```sql
SELECT year1880.id FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT id FROM data WHERE strftime("%Y", date) = "1880") as year1880

  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM data WHERE strftime("%Y", date) = "1881") as year1881
  ON year1880.id = year1881.id

  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM data WHERE strftime("%Y", date) = "1882") as year1882
  ON year1880.id = year1882.id

  ...

  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM data WHERE strftime("%Y", date) = "1900") as year1900
  ON year1880.id = year1900.id
  ;
```

Is this the most efficient way to make this query?  Could it be done in a closed
form so I don't need to generate a giant query with python?

The database is sqlite.

Comment: Maybe I've misunderstood, but what's wrong with `SELECT DISTINCT(id) FROM data WHERE strftime("%Y", date) BETWEEN 1880 AND 1900`? p.s. welcome to the forum!

Comment: I believe that gives me ids that appear anywhere between 1880 and 1900.  I want ids that appear during all of those years..

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT(id) FROM data WHERE strftime("%Y", date) BETWEEN 1880 AND 1900 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(id)) = 10`? or should that be 11? Whatever number suits! :-)

Comment: Looks like it should work to my ignorant eyes.  Mind submitting it as an answer so I can checkmark if it works when I get to see my data again?

Comment: I've completely revised my answer and added a new twist - you might want to take a look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should return all the `ids` that have at least one record for each year in your date range:

```
SELECT
  id
FROM
  <your table>
WHERE
  CAST(strftime("%Y", date) as decimal) BETWEEN <min year> AND <max year>
GROUP BY
  id
HAVING
  COUNT(DISTINCT strftime("%Y", date)) = <max year> - <min year> + 1
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Revised (more elegant and **definitely** more robust) answer:

I wanted to rethink my previous answer and spent some time preparing a fiddle (available [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=97f38847b328d40e61513bae0313ac39)) in order to (perhaps) come up with something better - I believe that I have succeeded.

First, I created a table derived from the question:

```
CREATE TABLE data
(
  uuid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  id CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  t_date DATE,
  CONSTRAINT id_t_date_uq UNIQUE (id, t_date)
);
```

Note that I changed the column name in the question from `date` to `t_date`. It is bad practice to use [SQL keywords](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/coding-standards/list-of-sql-reserved-words) as table or column names. It can lead to  potentially confusing error messages and makes debugging difficult (the underscore is your friend)!

Then I populated the table:

```
INSERT INTO data (id, t_date)
VALUES
('a', '1879-01-01'),  --- NOT IN DATE RANGE
('x', '1879-01-01'),

('a', '1881-01-01'),  -- There are 5 years in my sample range, therefore > 4
('b', '1881-01-01'),  -- should do the trick, however see discussion below
('c', '1881-01-01'),

('a', '1882-01-01'),
('b', '1882-01-01'),
('c', '1882-01-01'),
('c', '1882-06-15'),

('a', '1883-01-01'),
('b', '1883-01-01'),
('c', '1883-01-01'),

('a', '1884-01-01'),
('b', '1884-01-01'),
('c', '1884-01-01'),

('a', '1885-01-01'),
('b', '1885-01-01'),

('z', '1902-01-01');  -- NOT IN DATE RANGE
```

The first query I ran was this one (just as a check);

```
SELECT 
  id, COUNT(id)
FROM 
  data
WHERE
  CAST(strftime("%Y", t_date)AS INTEGER) BETWEEN 1880 AND 1900  -- use your SQLite function here
GROUP BY id
  HAVING COUNT(id) > 0;
```

Result:

```
id  COUNT(id)
a   5
b   5
c   5
```

Note that neither 'x' nor 'z' appear in the answer, because neither occur within the desired year range. Also, the overall count of 'a' is 6, but only 5 appear because the first one is in 1879 - again, outside the range and 'c' appears twice in 1882 but on different dates, so all is rosy in the garden!

Next, I ran my finished query (see explanation below):

```
SELECT
  id
FROM
  data
WHERE
  CAST(strftime("%Y", t_date) as INTEGER) BETWEEN 1880 AND 1900
GROUP BY
  id
HAVING
  COUNT(DISTINCT strftime("%Y", t_date)) = 
  (
    SELECT 
      COUNT(DISTINCT CAST(strftime("%Y", t_date) AS INTEGER)) AS yr_cnt
    FROM data
    WHERE CAST(strftime("%Y", t_date) AS INTEGER) BETWEEN 1880 AND 1900
  );
```

Result:

```
id
a
b
```

Which is the correct result because 'a' and 'b' are indeed the only two `id`s which appear in all 5 relevant years.

Now, you may be asking yourself why I put in the (apparently overkill) sub-`SELECT` to get the `COUNT(id)`. That is because of the potential for `"missing"` data. **If** you don't have data for **every** year between 1880 and 1900 (inclusive), then your `id`s will fail to appear, i.e. they'll fall short of the number of years.

Note that my simulated data only covered 5 years between the relevant years when there are, in fact, 21 - so my query using `COUNT(id) >= (1900 - 1880 + 1)` obviously failed to return any data. This is a more robust solution.

Comment: For some reason this gives me 0 results and @bbaird's answer gets the results.  But they look the same to me.

Comment: The way the answer looks now works and is very thorough. Ignore my previous comment. :)